# WSUS on Non-AD Enviroment

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-server-2016, wsus

I have a work-group Environment and WSUS installed on windows server 2016.
I edited the registery of clients as follows, but still I can't see my computer in WSUS Computers list.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"AcceptTrustedPublisherCerts"=dword:00000001
"ElevateNonAdmins"=dword:00000001
"TargetGroup"="HELPLING"
"TargetGroupEnabled"=dword:00000000
"WUServer"="http://****
"WUStatusServer"="http://***

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"AUOptions"=dword:00000004
"AUPowerManagement"=dword:00000001
"AutoInstallMinorUpdates"=dword:00000001
"DetectionFrequency"=dword:0000000a
"DetectionFrequencyEnabled"=dword:00000001
"IncludeRecommendedUpdates"=dword:00000001
"NoAUAsDefaultShutdownOption"=dword:00000001
"NoAUShutdownOption"=dword:00000001
"NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers"=dword:00000001
"NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000000
"RebootRelaunchTimeout"=dword:0000000a
"RebootRelaunchTimeoutEnabled"=dword:00000001
"RescheduleWaitTime"=dword:0000000a
"RescheduleWaitTimeEnabled"=dword:00000001
"ScheduledInstallDay"=dword:00000000
"ScheduledInstallTime"=dword:00000003
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000001 '
```

Answer (score 0):

You put **** in place of the server-name. Did you put the WSUS port-number in that string?
Default port is 8530 but you have to explicitly say so in the registry keys.
Otherwise it will still use the default HTPP:// port-number which is port 80.

Everything else looks OK to me. In fact I use nearly identical settings (slightly different time-out values) on my own deployment.

Comment: instead of starts are  http://Myserver:8530.

Comment: should I change any registery or GPO on my WSUS side?